# Does protobuf-net support nullable types?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Is it possible to generate nullable members in protobuf-net?

```
message ProtoBuf1 {
    optional Int32? databit = 1;
    optional Nullable<bool> databool = 2;
}
```

Comment: To clarify, protobuf-net supports nullable types, but .proto does not; I do not control .proto

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling null values in protobuffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227924/handling-null-values-in-protobuffers)

Answer (score 15):

Yes, but it doesn't *generate* them by default if you are doing codegen from .proto.

If this is just C#, of course, you don't **need** a .proto - just:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class ProgoBuf1
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int? Foo {get;set;}

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public float? Bar {get;set;}
}
```

If you *are* working from .proto, you could consider copying and editing `csharp.xslt` to suit your preferred layout.

Comment: does it support ALL nullable types - eg nullable DateTimes?

Comment: @mcmillab if it can serialize the value-type, then yes it should also be able to serialize the nullable form too. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: @MarcGravell for DateTime? how to specify default value ?

Comment: @BaltoStar it is awkward to express date time in attributes, so `[DefaultValue(...)]` might not work, but you could use `[ProtoMember(n)] public DateTime Foo {get;set;} = yourDefault; public bool ShouldSerializeFoo() => Foo != yourDefault;`

Comment: @MarcGravell please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39671574/protobuf-net-how-to-represent-datetime-in-c

Answer (score 13):

Here's my solution for nullable types when using Google's Protobuf .NET API which requires Protocol Buffers version 3. (Note that this is not using Marc Gravell's protobuf-net, so this isn't an exact answer to the question asked.)

In `NullableInt32.proto`:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message NullableInt32 {
  int32 value = 1;
}
```

In `NullableInt32Extensions.cs`:

```
public static class NullableInt32Extensions
{
  public static bool HasValue(this NullableInt32 source)
  {
    return source != null;
  }
}

public partial class NullableInt32
{
  public static implicit operator int? (NullableInt32 other)
  {
    return other == null ? (int?)null : other.Value;
  }

  public static implicit operator NullableInt32(int? other)
  {
    return other == null ? null : new NullableInt32 { Value = other.Value };
  }
}
```

This pattern can be used for any of the Protobuf non-length delimited scalar values—`double`, `float`, `int32`, `int64`, `uint32`, `uint64`, `sint32`, `sint64`, `fixed32`, `fixed64`, `sfixed32`, `sfixed64`, and `bool`.

---

Here's how all of this works. Say you have a `Record` message that has a `NullableInt32` field, and in this contrived example it's the only field.

In `Record.proto`:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "NullableInt32.proto";

message Record {
  NullableInt32 id = 1;
}
```

Once this is compiled to C# with Google's `protoc.exe`, you can treat the `Id` property almost exactly like a `Nullable<int>`.

```
var r = new Record();

// r.Id is null by default, but we can still call HasValue()
// because extension methods work on null references.
r.Id.HasValue(); // => false

// We can explicitly set Id to null.
r.Id = null;

// We can set Id to a primitive numeric value directly
// thanks to our implicit conversion operators.
r.Id = 1;

// We can also use NullableInt32 in any context that expects a
// Nullable<int>. The signature of the following method is
// bool Equals(int?, int?).
Nullable.Equals<int>(r.Id, 1); // => true

// We can explicitly set Id to a NullableInt32.
r.Id = new NullableInt32 { Value = 1 };

// Just like Nullable<int>, we can get or set the Value of a
// NullableInt32 directly, but only if it's not null. Otherwise,
// we'll get a NullReferenceException. Use HasValue() to avoid this.
if(r.Id.HasValue())
  r.Id.Value.ToString(); // => "1"

// Setting Id to 0 is the same as setting Id to a new
// NullableInt32 since the default value of int32 is 0.
// The following expressions are equivalent.
r.Id = 0;
r.Id = new NullableInt32();
r.Id = new NullableInt32 { Value = 0 };
r.Id.Value = 0; // as long as Id is not null
```

---

Finally, let's look at how our `Record` message will be transfered over the wire with different values for `Id`.

```
var r = new Record();

// When Id is null, Record is empty since it has no other fields.
// Explicitly setting Id to null will have the same effect as
// never setting it at all.
r.Id = null;
r.ToByteArray(); // => byte[0]

// Since NullableInt32 is a Protobuf message, it's encoded as a
// length delimited type. Setting Id to 1 will yield four bytes.
// The first two indicate the type and length of the NullableInt32
// message, and the last two indicate the type and value held within.
r.Id = 1;
r.ToByteArray(); // => byte[] {
                 //      0x0a, // field  = 1, type = 2 (length delimited)
                 //      0x02, // length = 2
                 //      0x08, // field  = 1, type = 0 (varint)
                 //      0x01, // value  = 1
                 //    }

// When Id is set to the default int32 value of 0, only two bytes
// are needed since default values are not sent over the wire.
// These two bytes just indicate that an empty NullableInt32 exists.
r.Id = 0;
r.ToByteArray(); // => byte[] {
                 //      0x0a, // field  = 1, type = 2 (length delimited)
                 //      0x00, // length = 0
                 //    }
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile " other.Value" does not exist.

Comment: @Asheh Did you compile the NullableInt32.proto file?

Comment: ah im using annotations so no

Answer (score 10):

## Proto 3

Import "wrappers.proto" supports nullable values:

- string(StringValue),
- int(Int32Value),
- bool(BoolValue)
- and etc

Full list of supported types - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/protobuf-data-types#nullable-types

Example:

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

message ProtoPerson {
    google.protobuf.StringValue firstName = 1;
    google.protobuf.StringValue lastName = 2;
    google.protobuf.StringValue address1 = 3;
    google.protobuf.Int32Value age = 4;
}
```