# Are there good reasons to use .proto files on a single-platform system?

Tags: .net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

We're developing a few services that communicate with each other via Protocol Buffers. All the services are written on .NET.  I don’t foresee migrating them off of .NET.   I don’t foresee using the same messages with services on other platforms.

The messages are currently written in .proto.  The code generation step seems superfluous to me.

Aside from cross-platform compatibility (which is not a concern to us), is there any reason to write messages in .proto instead of directly in a .NET language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the setup you describe (.NET-to-.NET, unlikely to need cross-platform), then I would say "no". We do a **lot** of things that meet this category, and we just work code-first, i.e. we write the C# types, and just use them. This gives us total control and flexibility over the types, and avoids unnecessary build/tooling steps.

Indeed, that was actually the core motivation-for, and purpose-of protobuf-net: for it to be able to work from regular c# types without requiring definition in a DSL, like all other .NET serializers do (`XmlSerializer`, `DataContractSerializer`, `JavaScriptSerializer`, etc).

Note that while protobuf-net includes a `.GetProto<T>` feature, this has not yet been re-implemented in v2; however, that is next on my list now that the cross-platform precompiler is done and working. My point here is: it is likely that if there *becomes* a requirement to do cross-platform etc, then protobuf-net may be able to help generate the .proto for you from the existing contracts.

If you are concerned that you *might* at some point need interop to other platforms, stick to the core protobuf feature set. Avoid protobuf-net additions, like:

- inheritance
- .NET-specific type support (`DateTime`, `decimal`, etc)
- reference tracking
- dynamic type support

Comment: Thanks for the reply Marc.  What sparked this question were some truly optional fields that would naturally map to Nullable<T>.   I ran across your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763875/does-protobuf-net-support-nullable-types). Customizing the xslt strikes me as not simple. I would probably be more tempted to use a default or a flag to indicate a null value.  Do you intend to support Nullable<T> in .GetProto<T> ?

Comment: @Kenn I will *try* to support whatever I can ;p That will map to "optional" in .proto, which should be fine.

Comment: That would make .GetProto<T> asymmetric with the code generator, if I'm not mistaken, considering the generator does not map optional to Nullable.

Comment: @Kenn c# has more features than .proto; it is always going to be asymmetric in some way. Equally, .proto has no concept of "arrays" vs "lists" vs "ilists" - it just has "repeated". And IIRC (although possibly only with `detectMissing` enabled), protogen *does* use `Nullable<T>`, along with conditional serialization specifies. Pretty sure `Nullable<T>` is part of the the xslt.

Comment: Point taken, Marc.  Thanks for the tip on detectMissing.  It's a shame I didn't make a new stackoverflow question.