# protobuf-net : how to represent DateTime in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, timestamp, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

`protogen.exe` generates this pattern for a `proto2` message field of type `long` :

```
private long _Count = default(long);
[global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = false, Name=@"Count", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.TwosComplement)]
[global::System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(default(long))]
public long Count
{
  get { return _Count; }
  set { _Count = value; }
}
```

but as `proto2` does not include a date-time type ( and `protobuf-net` does not support `proto3` which includes `google.protobuf.Timestamp` ) it's not clear how to represent `DateTime` in manually coded C# proto object.

This is probably wrong :

```
private DateTime _When = DateTime.MinValue;
[global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = false, Name=@"When", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.Default)]
[global::System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(DateTime.MinValue)]
public DateTime When
{
  get { return _When; }
  set { _When = value; }
}
```

What is the correct way to decorate `DateTime` properties for use with `protobuf-net` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you want it to look like on the wire. If you want it to be a `long` (delta into epoch), then : do that. For example:

```
[ProtoMember(...)] public long Foo {get;set;}
```

If you want it to be a `long` on the wire and a `DateTime` in your code: do that:

```
 public DateTime Foo {get;set;}
 [ProtoMember(...)] private long FooSerialized {
    get { return DateTimeToLong(Foo); }
    set { Foo = LongToDateTime(value); }
  }
```

If you don't care and just want to store a `DateTime`, do that:

```
[ProtoMember(...)] public DateTime Foo {get;set;}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc. Yes I need public property of type DateTime, so option 2 or 3 are advised. But I'm not understanding option 3 because proto2 doesn't support DateTime -- how is the DateTime represented on the wire ?

Comment: @Balto see Bcl.Proto. basically, protobuf-net makes something up. If you need xplat: use the long trick (#2), IMO

Comment: I assume `DateTime` default value is `["1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM"]` = `DateTime.MinValue`.  But what about `DateTime DataFormat` ?

Comment: Also if go with option 2 how to implement `DateTime?` ? possibly with `long?` ?

Answer (score 1):

The `Timestamp` type is now supported:

```
[global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = false, Name=@"When",
    DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.WellKnown)]
public DateTime When {get;set;}
```